# Angular 8 + IE 11: Some polyfills are missed

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

We need to make Angular 8 and IE 11 work together.

We use target=es5, and ng serve creates pollyfills-es5.js, that contains required array-includes polyfill, but there is the error in console: ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'. Other code works fine, some components displayed on screen.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "module": "esnext"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.es5.json

```
{
  "extends": "./src/tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
...
"build":{
    ...
   "configurations":{ 
         "es5": {
              "tsConfig": "./tsconfig.es5.json"
            }
    }
    ...
},
"serve":{
    ...
   "configurations":{ 
         "es5": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:es5"
            }
    }
    ...
}
```

**browserlist**: last 1 chrome version, IE 11

to start code we use: **ng serve --live-reload=false --configuration=es5**

In resulted index.html we have

```html
<script src="runtime.js" defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills.js" defer></script>
<script src="styles.js" defer></script>
<script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
<script src="vendor.js" defer></script>
<script src="main.js" defer></script></body>
```

But in console we have: **ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The angular-cli only adds the IE11 polyfills it needs to the `polyfills-es5`. So in this file you will only find polyfills to make angular work. Angular does not use `Array.includes` in its source code, so if you want this to be in your polyfills, you have to add it to your own polyfill.ts file.

```
import 'core-js/modules/es.array.includes'
```

This will then end up in the `polyfills.js` not the `polyfills-es5.js`. You can find more information [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4128)

Answer (score 0):

For me adding the below line in `polyfill.ts` worked in Angular 10

```
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```